# How to connect with Team Foundation Server from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I downloaded and installed the Team Foundation server for Visual studio 2010 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15070).  Visual Studio Professional 2010 was installed  before.  Both programs were installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0.

However, I do not see the option to connect to Team Foundation server in Tools my Visual Studio.  So I do not know what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't there a `Team Foundation Server Console` in your `Start` -> `All Programs` to setup and configure the TFS? And if that is done you can connect with TFS by following [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2009/10/21/tutorial-getting-started-with-tfs-in-vs2010.aspx).

Comment: Somehow I got the impression that connection to Team Foundations server in Visual Studio should be through Tools menu item.  However, it is from the Team menu item- so I started working immediately after reading the post - thanks

Comment: Luckily, I got the answer before the question was closed ...